# PHP SSH2 PECL extension issues

Tags: php, linux, ssh

Before I begin, I'm aware of phpseclib and from what I've ready it's the way you should normally go. Unfortunately I'm working on an older script, and I'm trying to avoid the time needed to set up phpseclib, test on local environment, put on production, test on production, refactor my script, etc. I'm hoping someone can help resolve my issue with ssh2.

I've used the following script to ssh a file to a client's server. It has worked fine for years.

```
<?php

$url = 'their.url.com';
$userName = 'name';
$password = 'pass';

$conn = ssh2_connect($url, 22);
$auth = ssh2_auth_password($conn, $userName, $password);

// Determine whether this is a file path that needs to be opened or not
$localFilePath = 'test123.txt';
$openFile = fopen($localFilePath, "r");

$fileName = 'test.txt';
// Their server path
$remoteFilePath = "/Orders/".$fileName;

if ($auth === true) {
    // Transfer file
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn);

    file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://".$sftp.$remoteFilePath, $openFile);
}
```

WHAT HAPPENED:
My client moved his stuff to a different server. It broke the connection, he freaked out, etc., etc. He gave me updated credentials to the new server, and I have confirmed the protocal is SFTP - SSH File Transfer Protocal.

THE ISSUE:
The file transfer is no longer working after updating the ssh combo url/credentials.

WHAT I'VE TRIED:
I tried a test file transfer using Linux (not PHP) and it worked. I also ssh'd in using Filezilla and transferred a file that way, no problem. so I have confirmed that the host/user/pass combo is correct.

I dumped out the result of the file_put_contents, and it is false.

I dumped out $conn, $auth, and $sftp, and what "ssh2.sftp://".$sftp.$remoteFilePath looks like, and the results are (in order)

1. resource(27) of type (SSH2 Session)
2. bool(true)
3. resource(30) of type (SSH2 SFTP)
4. ssh2.sftp://Resource id #30/Orders/test.txt

Note that test.txt is a very tiny file to rule out file size issues.

I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the ssh2 PECL extension.

I am convinced this is due to an issue on their end, because this script has always worked before, I'm just baffled as to why things are failing now that they're on their new server, and I'm not sure what to do further to diagnose the problem. I can't think of any change that's been made to my server that would affect this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So far so good... but you didn't mention what the issue is...

Comment: @Dekel Apologies, I thought I was clear, but I edited the post a bit. The issue is the file transfer isn't occuring, and file_put_contents now returns false. So the file transfer is failing somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `ssh2.sftp://` stream directly?

```
file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$userName}:{$password}@{$url}:22/{$remoteFilePath}", $openFile);
```

It should work without all the ssh connection, authentication, moving to sftp, etc..

Comment: Thanks so much! No idea why this worked and the other stuff no longer is, but I'll take it!